# your family is opening gifts "buzzed on" eggnog

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of "[buzzed on eggnog](https://matadornetwork.com/notebook/10-reasons-pilot-isnt-cool-think-1-makes-worthwhile/)" in "your family is opening gifts buzzed on eggnog"? Does "buzz" mean being excited in this context, somehow? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eggnog is an alcoholic drink. 'Buzzed' means somewhat drunk, like 'tipsy'. So, yes, excited.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!